# Can I order specific storage size using softlayer API - like 65GB

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I listed the storage spaces for endurance storage(package ID=240) using SL APIs, it is not returning all the spaces and I can see only few :
20,40,80,100,250,500,1000,2000,8000 (in GBs).

Is it possible to order storage of specific size like 65GB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to order a block storage endurance of a specific size.

With the following rest api call you will be able to retrieve all the item prices to order a new block storage endurance:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[id,description,attributes[attributeType]],pricingLocationGroup[locations]]
```

You have to use the "packageId 759" to order a block storage endurance because it is the package that the control portal use.

You will get a response like below example:

```
{ 'id': 193433,
      'item': {'attributes': [{
                   'attributeType': {'keyName': 'CAPACITY_RANGE_MINIMUM',
                                                 'name': 'Capacity range minimum'},
                    'id': 6289,
                    'itemId': 9623,},
                   {'attributeType': {'keyName': 'CAPACITY_RANGE_MAXIMUM',
                                                 'name': 'Capacity range maximum'},
                    'id': 6291,
                    'itemId': 9623,}],
               'description': 'Storage space for 2 IOPS per GB',
               'id': 9623}},
{'id': 189543,
  'item': {'attributes': [{'attributeType': {'keyName': 'CAPACITY_RANGE_MINIMUM',
                                             'name': 'Capacity range minimum'},
                           'id': 6201,
                           'itemAttributeTypeId': 133,
                           'itemId': 9575,
                           'value': '100'},
                          {'attributeType': {'keyName': 'CAPACITY_RANGE_MAXIMUM',
                                             'name': 'Capacity range maximum'},
                           'id': 6203,
                           'itemAttributeTypeId': 134,
                           'itemId': 9575,
                           'value': '1000'}],
           'description': '100 - 1000 IOPS',
           'id': 9575},
  'pricingLocationGroup': {'description': 'Location Group 5',
                           'id': 509,
                           'locationGroupTypeId': 82,
                           'locations': [{'id': 221842,
                                          'longName': 'Tokyo 1',
                                          'name': 'tok01',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 352494,
                                          'longName': 'Hong Kong 2',
                                          'name': 'hkg02',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 449604,
                                          'longName': 'Tokyo 2',
                                          'name': 'tok02',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 2344397,
                                          'longName': 'Tokyo 5',
                                          'name': 'tok05',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 221843,
                                          'longName': 'Singapore 2',
                                          'name': 'sng02',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 2344395,
                                          'longName': 'Tokyo 4',
                                          'name': 'tok04',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 221845,
                                          'longName': 'Hong Kong 1',
                                          'name': 'hkg01',
                                          'statusId': 2},
                                         {'id': 224092,
                                          'longName': 'Singapore 1',
                                          'name': 'sng01',
                                          'statusId': 2}],
                           'name': 'Location Group 5',
                           'securityLevelId': ''}},
```

You can search the item prices id e.g. by 'description': 'Storage space for 2 IOPS per GB', depending of the "iops" selected and the data center too, in this case I selected for "iops = 2".

The item prices that do not have locations are standard, it means that are available for all locations.

You can use the following structure to your json body request:

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
            "location": 1441195,
            "packageId": 759,
            "prices": [
               {
                 "id": 193433 // 'description': 'Storage space for 2 IOPS per GB'
               },
               {
                 "id": 193373 // 'description': '2 IOPS per GB'
               },
               {
                 "id": 189433 // 'description': 'Storage as a Service'
               },
               {
                 "id": 189443 // 'description': 'Block Storage'
               }
            ],
            "quantity": 1,
            "useHourlyPricing": true,
            "osFormatType": {
                "id": 28,
                "keyName": "WINDOWS",
                "name": "Windows 2003"
             },
           "volumeSize": 65
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what if I need to order performance storage type?

Comment: To order a performance storage type you can use the same packageId and the structure json body, just you have to add the "iops" attribute. You can search the item price id depending of the ¨volumeSize¨ you are using, e.g. for a ¨volumeSize = 65¨ you can search with the following: 'description': '40 - 79 GBs',  you have to see the location too.

Comment: For the ¨iops¨ attribute e.g. if you select ¨iops = 110¨ you can search the item prices id this the following: 'description': '100 - 2000 IOPS', this is for the second item price.

Comment: I suggest you to compare with the control portal data when you are searching the item prices id to add them to the json body.